# kivy in virtual environment, window provider error (linux)

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, kivy, conda

I am trying to get the [kivy framework](https://kivy.org/#home) to run on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine with anaconda python.

I have followed the installation instructions provided [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#installation-in-a-virtual-environment) both in virtualenv and conda virtualenv environments.

In both kinds of environments I encountered the same issue. When trying to run a kivy program with `python file.py` I get (among others) the following messages and the program doesn't execute:

```
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (default, [...]) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 ...]
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
    egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name bcm
...
```

However, when I run a file from an interactive python session using `execfile('file.py')` it works without problems.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you had a clean installation?
try this in your virtual environment:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
cd pygame
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```